# Proving that when gf is injective, f is surjective

Tags: functions

For functions $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$ (A, B, C nonempty sets)
I have started off with presuming $g \circ f$ is injective (given)

$\exists x_1, x_2 \in A$ such that $g \circ f (x_1) = g \circ f (x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2$.

I have tried to prove this by assuming f is not surj, ie $\exists a \in A$ such that $f(a) \not \in B$. Then I tried to say that since $g \circ f$ is surjective, $g \circ f(a) \in C$. Not sure where to progress from here, any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: A standard exercise would be to show that $f$ is *injective*.

Answer (score 2):

The statement you are trying to prove is false. Take $A=\{a\}$, $B=\{b_1, b_2\}$ and $C=\{c_1, c_2\}$.

Further, define $f(a)=b_1$, and define $g(b_1)=g(c_1), g(b_2)=c_2$.

Then, $g\circ f$ is injective. However, $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: How is f not surjective? Ran(f) = {b} = B

Comment: @Ophe Fixed the example